# prove the lim and the Hospital's rule

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be real valued functions defined on $(a,b)$. 
If $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) $ exists in $\Bbb R$ and $\lim_{x \to a^+} g(x)= \infty $,
prove that $\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$.

I have no idea how to approach this question can you guys give be some hint?
is this kind of obvious to say 
$$\frac{\text{finite value}} \infty  = 0?$$

What do you have to show it here?

Comment: [What should I do if I don't know where to start?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599334/what-should-i-do-if-i-dont-know-where-to-start)

Comment: Do you mean that $\lim_{x\to a^+} g(x) = \infty$, perchance? Also, this isn't related to L'Hospital's rule: L'Hospital's rule would have something to do with differentiability, which isn't mentioned here.

Comment: Why you mention L'hopital's rule??

Comment: oh yea.... the letter was so small i thought its negative-....T.Bongers

Comment: I think you need that $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ exists but also be $\neq 0$.

Comment: Under this assumption the result follows immediately.

Comment: How you show  $lim_{x\to a^+} f(x) \neq  0?$

Comment: @LuisValerin: $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{x}{1/x^{2}} = 0$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Can you begin by proving the following fact about sequences?

> If $a_n$ is a bounded sequence, and $b_n \to \infty$, then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 0$$

Proceeding directly from the definitions is advised here.

---

One way to proceed with proving this is to suppose that $|a_n| < M$ for some positive $M$ and all $n$. Then choosing $n$ large enough guarantees that $|b_n| > \frac{M}{\epsilon}$ for any preassigned error $\epsilon$. Now consider $|a_n / b_n|$. This proof can be immediately translated into language about functions, using the fact that if the limit as $x \to a^+$ exists, then $f$ is bounded near $a$.

Comment: Why the downvote? If there's a technical error or a suggestion for improvement, I'd be glad to consider it.

Comment: @LuisValerin: I am unable to figure out what is the problem when $f(x) \to 0$. Please elaborate.

Comment: @LuisValerin If $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = 0$, then one can choose, for example, $M = 1$.

Comment: Yes you right guys my mistake i found an invalid example. In order to this i have deleted the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose (without lose of generally) that $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)=b>0$. Then $$0\leq \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\leq \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{2b}{g(x)}=0.$$ And the result follows inmediately from the squeeze theorem.

Comment: The case when $b<0$ can be work similar. And when $b=0$ is an indeterminate case.

Comment: what is the issue when $b = 0$. In this case also the final answer comes to be $0$.